# How to allow only logged in user to to view static html page in react, nginx and dotnetcore backend

Tags: reactjs, nginx, .net-core

I've a react application with username/password login authentications with dotnetcore backend. I want to add a static html page for terms and condition as a separate static html url e.g. `localhost/terms/index.html`. I can put `terms/index.html` in the public folder of the react application or serve as a separate url in the nginx. But I want to make static html page `terms/index.html` available to only logged in users in react app. With current implementation, `terms/index html` is available even after I logged out of the react application. How can I do this either in react app or in nginx configuration?

```
    location / {
        root   html\myreactappwithlogin;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    
    location /terms {
        root   html\terms;
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the terms page to your react app? Then the behavior becomes the same as any other route in your application. Your nginx will always send the main `index.html`. React will be downloaded as usual and then the client routing will load the `/terms` page.

If you're worried about your react bundle size increasing because of adding this static page to your react app, you can make use of code splitting by using dynamic import syntax (import(path_to_file))

Comment: That is a simple alternative that I can do. But I want to have this page as an Html and don't want to convert to react as I have frequent update to this page and contains internal links

Comment: @Aung How will a user from the web provide credentials when they access the page? If you have cookie auth, then you can host your own node server that simply serves the page after checking the cookie. Otherwise the simplest solution still seems to be to add to react. If there's any sensitive data, you can load it through env variables